# Can't compile rust program

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and  made a simple rust program(hello world). I installed rust and Visual Studio from here - https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ and restarted the device. However when I type in `rustc <path>` on command prompt, I get:

```rust
error: linker `link.exe` not found
  |
  = note: The system cannot find the file specified. (os error 2)

note: the msvc targets depend on the msvc linker but `link.exe` was not found

note: please ensure that VS 2013, VS 2015 or VS 2017 was installed with the Visual C++ option

error: aborting due to previous error
```

What's wrong?

**Update**

I updated my system path to include `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\Hostx64\x64`, but now it gives this error:

```rust
error: linking with `link.exe` failed: exit code: 1181
  |
  = note: "link.exe" "/NOLOGO" "/NXCOMPAT" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "main.main.7rcbfp3g-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "/OUT:main.exe" "main.4s37gsrti678ik8u.rcgu.o" "/OPT:REF,NOICF" "/DEBUG" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\intrinsic.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\liballoc.natvis" "/NATVIS:C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\etc\\libcore.natvis" "/LIBPATH:C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libstd-b2f27b8d08c4688f.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libpanic_unwind-9c73c9c2e052b2f1.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libbacktrace-7a588e8fa018f6bc.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_demangle-74b71f441b8acffe.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libhashbrown-42efce06651eab9c.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_alloc-7518db6030684168.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libunwind-f7edde5930d50b47.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcfg_if-30189c8e78e151e8.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liblibc-5f5719f1cab83a12.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\liballoc-f297c401e81b90c6.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\librustc_std_workspace_core-f8c80c1aefab6a32.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcore-6d66b6e58725d3ed.rlib" "C:\\Users\\Sid\\.rustup\\toolchains\\stable-x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\rustlib\\x86_64-pc-windows-msvc\\lib\\libcompiler_builtins-1f6a73e107798f53.rlib" "advapi32.lib" "ws2_32.lib" "userenv.lib" "msvcrt.lib"
  = note: LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'advapi32.lib'


error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: Visual studio isn't enough, you also need the entire MSVC C/C++ toolchain if memory serves me right.

Comment: Thanks, where can I get this?

Comment: I did select the Visual C++ option while downloading.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs/issues/1455) is your exact issue along with resolution steps. make sure your path was updated after installing the build tools (I.e. don't use an old shell opened before installation), make sure link.exe is in your path and you should be good

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to use `rustc` directly. Install [rustup](https://rustup.rs/) and then do everything using cargo. It should all just work.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld, thanks for the help. I updated the path but I get the error as mentioned in the updated question.

Comment: @Sid and now this is your problem: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/43039#issuecomment-317237291 with solution in there. there's a reason rustup is recommended.

Comment: @Sid - Did you find any answer useful? It is good to provide feedback. Thanks.

Comment: @sancho.s I had actually accepted an answer and given it a bounty as well. For some reason it has been deleted.

Comment: @Sid - Hmmm, strange.

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51659) reports your exact problem.
So the solution seems to use VS installer and installing C++ for Desktop Module.

Use of `rustup` is a matter of convenience but shouldn't be mandatory.